# Python: separating less than 25 int and greater than 25 int inputs then working with those numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write  a Python program that reads in a series of positive integers and writes  out the product of all the integers less than 25 and the sum of all the  integers greater than or equal to 25. Use 0 as a sentinel value.

```
def main():
    user_input = 1
    while user_input != 0:
        user_input = int(input("Enter positive integers, then type 0 when finnished. "))
        if (user_input) < 25:
            product = 1
            product = (user_input) * product
        else:
            (user_input) >= 25
            sum = 0
            sum = (user_input) + sum

    print('The product off all the integers less than 25 is ', product, "and the sum of all the integers greater than 25 is ", sum, ".")
main()
```

Here is what I have so far. This is my first python code for my intro to computer science class.

My major roadblocks is that the sentinel value has to be zero and I user_input to multiply by the product which is just zeroing everything out.

Comment: Why don't you test for zero *before* checking whether it's above or below 25?

Comment: You need to initialise your sentinel values outside of the while loop

Comment: Your first task is to review your textbook and other course materials, or you will continue to have major roadblocks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor corrections to your code.

- Initialise the sentinels outside of the loop or they get reset every time.
- Else clause syntax error and changed to an `elif`
- Renamed `sum` to not clash with python builtin `sum`
- Protected `product` total from multiply by zero on exit.

Code:

```
def main():
    sum_total, product = 0, 1
    user_input = 1
    while user_input != 0:
        user_input = int(input("Enter positive integers, then type 0 when finnished. "))
        if 0 < user_input < 25:
            product *= user_input
        elif user_input >= 25:
            sum_total += user_input
    print("The product off all the integers less than 25 is ", product)
    print("The sum of all the integers greater than 25 is ", sum_total)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I actually had my output window cut off short due to monitor spacing and kept thinking your code was off by something. 

"The product of all the integers less than 25 is  6 and the sum of all the integers greater than 25...."  

This was all I was reading and I messed around and looked up loads of tutorials and examples and for the life of me couldn't find a mistake. 


elif is something I really did not know yet, that will be really helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check if the the sentinel value is 0, if so just add the value to it.